# Creating React Package

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, yarnpkg

I created react package and published it on npm

Now when I install it in another app and start to use it this error come across me

```
Failed to compile

./node_modules/react-clicky/Clicky.js
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (6:9)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| // @props style?: object, onClick?: void, url?: string, scroll?: string
| class Clicky extends React.Component {
|   onClick = () => {
|       const { onClick, url, scroll } = this.props;
```

Comment: Can you link to your code at all? Also did you bundle the project?

Comment: Tall I don't bandle my code because I want to make it easy to use . This is my code https://github.com/yamankatby/react-clicky

Comment: bundling your code does make it easy to use, as a user I don't plan on debugging a depedency, I plan on saying `import Clicky from 'clicky-react'` and that it just works. So bundling provides a smaller package and will figure your file issue of an appropriate loader needed because it will know that this is a commonjs file type.

Comment: Tall Paul is right. You should bundle your code so other people can use it. If you don't bundle it, you're expecting every project that implements your code to be able to handle the syntax you have written your code with. Not everyone uses es6 classes and the class property transform. This is likely the issue with the parent project you are trying to import into. The error message suggests you need a (babel?) loader to handle the syntax that's in your package.